# Help with design and (more importantly) unit testing. (Something like strategy pattern)

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop

I'm working on simple benchmark "framework" (reason: boredom and practice). 
Now I'm trying to get my head around something. 
First things first:

```
class DataManager {

    private $persistanceStrategy;

    public function __construct(IPersistence $persistenceStrategy) {
        $this->persistanceStrategy = $persistenceStrategy;
    }

    public function saveData() {
        $this->persistanceStrategy->saveData($params);
    }

    public function getData() {
        $this->persistanceStrategy->getData($params);
    }
}

interface IPersistence {
    public function saveData(array $params);
    public function getData(array $params);
}

class XMLPersistence implements IPersistence {

    // Params would contain something like path to the
    // xml file, and unique name of some tag
    public function saveData(array $params) {
         // write something to xml file
    }
    public function getData(array $params) {
       // get something from xml file
    }
}

class DBPersistence implements IPersistence {
 // $params would contain unique name of data that is needed
 // and data for db connection
  ...
}

class SessionPersistence implements IPersistence {
  ....
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better way of designing this part of code.
2. How would someone unit test DataManager class, and "strategy" classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using the stragety pattern here makes sense to me, so I don't have any improvement suggestions.
2. Here's a blog with one way to test your DataManager class. Basically you give it a mock strategy class and make sure that the proper strategy methods are indeed called.

   [Testing Your Mocks](http://elblinkin.info/2011/06/testing-your-mocks/)

   I think testing the persistence classes would straightforward, make sure the XMLPersistence makes expected xml data, DB puts data in expected database, and maybe Session is asserted against an expected serialization.

Comment: You're welcome! It was familiar since that blog just came up a couple weeks ago on [Planet PHPUnit](http://planet.phpunit.de/).